# NextJS 14 - Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div> when using special characters

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm facing a strange problem with next js. So I have a span that contains some static text. If in this span I set some text containing spécial characters like 'é' then I have 2 errors in the console :

- Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
- Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a  in .

So for example if my span is like this

```
<span>Numéro de téléphone</span>
```

There is the error in the console and if the span is like this :

```
<span>Numero de telephone</span>
```

Then everything is ok ^^'

Can you help me understand what is going wrong please ?

Comment: Yes, it was due to an extension (LastPass), thank you